# How to get all variants of the ingredients for a recipe?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I have an auto-crafter plugin for a Minecraft server, what's important is that it lookups the recipe of the item it is to craft using the ingredient map `((ShapedRecipe)recipe).getIngredientMap();`. the ingredient map links a character in the recipe to an `ItemStack`. The issue is for a recipe (such as a stick) that uses variants of wood types, when getting the `ItemStack` from the map, it is always an Oak plank, even though sticks in-game can be crafted with other wood varients.  is there any way to get all variants of wood from the `ItemStack` in the ingredient map?

Comment: What is your spigot MC version? If below 1.13, it's with byte data. Else, it's like "OAK_PLANK" so check for "JUNGLE_PLANK" etc

Comment: the version I am using is 1.19, the problem is that spigot uses `MaterialChoice` to allow multiple types of materials, but when I get the `ItemStack` from the ingredient map it is always OAK_PLANK for recipes like sticks or chests that can be made from varying types of planks

Answer (score 0):

`ShapelessRecipe` also has a method called `getChoiceMap` which can be used to get the recipe choices for a given recipe, which allows a search of variant materials that can also be used.